# DataStore in Roblox Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

so I am currently trying to get a save script to work with a mouse click event game. It is supposed to save how many clicks (Points) a player has. The problem is, that it doesn't seem to be saving at all. The leaderboard/mouse click event works, there are no output/script analysis errors, and the script is in ServerScriptService.

Here is the code:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
classData = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlayClass")
pointData = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlayPoints")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        pointData:GetAsync("Player_"..player.UserId)
    end
    )
    if success then
        print("Loading Success!")
    end
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        classData:GetAsync("Player_"..player.UserId)
    end
    )
    if success then
        print("Loading Success!")
    end

    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local Points = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    Points.Name = "Points"

    local Class = Instance.new("StringValue", leaderstats)
    Class.Name = "Class"
    Class.Value = "Wannabe"
    PlayerClass = player.leaderstats.Class
    PlayerPoints = player.leaderstats.Points
end)

workspace:WaitForChild("Sign")



workspace.Part.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)
    workspace.Sign.Value.Value = workspace.Sign.Value.Value + 1
    workspace.Sign.SurfaceGui.SIGN.Text = workspace.Sign.Value.Value
    PlayerPoints.Value = workspace.Sign.Value.Value



    if PlayerPoints.Value < 49
    then
        PlayerClass.Value = "Wannabe"
    end

    if PlayerPoints.Value > 49
    then
        PlayerClass.Value = "Beginner"
    end

    if PlayerPoints.Value > 124
    then
        PlayerClass.Value = "Novice"
    end

    if PlayerPoints.Value > 249
    then
        PlayerClass.Value = "Intermediate"
    end

    if PlayerPoints.Value > 374
    then
        PlayerClass.Value = "Pro"
    end

    if PlayerPoints.Value > 499
    then
        PlayerClass.Value = "God"
    end

end
)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        pointData:SetAsync("Player_"..player.UserId, PlayerPoints.Value)
    end
    )
    if success then
        print ("Saving Success!")
    end
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        classData:SetAsync("Player_"..player.UserId, PlayerClass.Value)
    end
    )
    if success then
        print("Saving Success!")
    end
end)
```

It prints Loading success, but it doesn't print Saving success.
EDIT: I tried adding an else statement to see the error, but it still doesn't print anything.

Comment: if you add an else statement, you can print out the err variable and see what went wrong

Comment: So, when I add the error message, it still just doesn't print anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can duplicate your issue, using a blank game, the part, and the script. As Kylaaa mentioned in his comment, if you do this:

```
if success then
    print ("Saving Success!")
else
    print (err)
end
```

...it will show you the error. I'm not sure from your comment if you tried it that way. Also, I did not get the error every time in my output. In my case the error was: "403: Cannot write to DataStore from studio if API access is not enabled." After enabling it, the "Saving Success" showed up just fine.

Comment: Oh okay. I was doing it as "warn (err)" just because that's how a person did it in a video. I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: hm. works with warn(err) for me as well. Does it go at all into that event handler? did you try putting a print at the beginning of that function?

Comment: print (game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player))? I just tried putting in a random print function in the middle of the code, and it did print out.